# C++ functors behavior

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


struct cmp {
        bool operator()(const int& i, const int&  j) const{
            return false;
        }   
} ;

struct cmp2 {
        bool operator()(const int& i, const int&  j) const{
            return false;
        }   
} cmp2_item;


class Solution {
public:

    vector<int> smth(vector<int> arr, int k) {
        // nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+k, arr.end(), cmp); #ERROR
        // nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+k, arr.end(), cmp()); #WORKS
        // nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+k, arr.end(), cmp2_item); # WORKS
        // sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), cmp); #ERROR
        // sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), cmp()); #WORKS
        // set<int, cmp> s; # WORKS
        // set<int, cmp2_item> s; # ERROR
        return {};
    }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Solution s;
    s.smth({}, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to understand why this code behaves in this way.

- for nth_element we expect a functor so it makes sense to include like cmp(), but why does it start working without the (), when i instantiate the struct and use that?
- Similar in sort
- while when using it for a comparator for a set, it only works if the struct is not instantiated and without the ()

Can someone please clarify using the signatures why this is so?

**nth_element**:  `template< class RandomIt, class Compare > void nth_element ( RandomIt first, RandomIt nth, RandomIt last, Compare comp );`

**sort**

```
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```

**set**:

```
           class Compare = less<T>,        // set::key_compare/value_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<T>      // set::allocator_type
           > class set;
```

Comment: "instantiate" means something else. The right term is to "create an object (of such-and-such type)". *"makes sense to include like cmp(), but why does it start working without the ()"* There's some misunderstanding here. `cmp()` is a constructor call, the `()` is not related to `cmp` having an overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: yes i understood that only - so calling cmp() would be just like creating an object of cmp type and hence it would work as it takes an object ?

Comment: Sounds correct.

Comment: Still confused about set comparator, wiki says "This can be a function pointer or a function object" is cmp the functor but cmp2_item not?

Comment: `cmp the functor but cmp2_item not?` `cmp` is a type.

Comment: @sww The wiki is correct, but it seems to talk about the comaprator object itself (stored inside of the `set`), not about the template parameter. The template parameter must be *the type of* the comparator. The comparator object (of that type) is then default-constructed, unless you pass one to the `set` constructor. E.g. if `cmp` wasn't default-constructible, you'd have to do `// set<int, cmp> s(cmp(/*...*/));`.

Comment: No, `cmp2_item` is a "functor". I guess you could also call `cmp` a "functor", but it would be a shorthand for "a functor type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of this is that `cmp2_item` is not a type, its an instance of the type cmp2. So you can't pass that as a class type. You might be able to do:

```
    set<int, cmp> s; //# WORKS
    set<int, decltype(cmp2_item)> s2; //# NOW WORKS
```

For these:

```
    // Not ok because cmp is not a function comparison object, its a type
    nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+k, arr.end(), cmp); #ERROR
    // Ok because this is effectively passing a functor (and not just a type) 
    // I believe this takes a copy of the functor type (by construction), I 
    // am not quite so clear on the inner workings of the compiler in this
    // case. I guess its by type comparison, but possible compiler
    // implementation specific?
    nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+k, arr.end(), cmp()); #WORKS
    // This is ok because it passes an actual comparison object (that has
    // operator () defined).
    nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin()+k, arr.end(), cmp2_item); # WORKS
```

Basically you have to look more closely at what you are passing: a type, an object or a function - and what the specific STL accepts as a parameter.

Note:

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

See here: [enter link description here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)

Comment: "its an instance of an object of type cmp2". No, it is an instance of the type cm2. A instance of a type is an object.

Comment: haha, ok - but if you want to be really semantically correct its an instance of the type "cmp2" - corrected, thanks :)